# How to investigate a crash, based on memory offset

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, dll, memory-address

My company is delivering a DLL, which is tested on a daily basis.
This morning it crashed and the C stack trace mentioned the following location of the crash:

```
[<product>.dll+0x279a30] // this stack trace contains no reference towards any function.
```

As the DLL is compiled in Release mode (using Visual Studio), this is not very interesting (there is no debugging information present in a Release DLL). I've tried reproducing the crash using a DLL, compiled in Debug mode, but there there is no crash.

Now I'm thinking of doing two compilations: one for Debug and one for Release mode, and in case of a crash in Release mode, I'd like to use the mentioned memory address to find more information in the Debug DLL, but there I have a doubt: I expect the memory addresses, mentioned in Debug and Release DLL, to be completely different (e.g. there are not asserts in Release mode), so I'm afraid that my procedure has no sense.

Does anybody have an idea how I can proceed here? Does anybody know how I could use the memory address, mentioned in the C stack trace? (for your information, I have the *.pdb files but I don't know how to use them (cvdump.exe and Visual Studio don't manage opening the files))

Comment: by definition you cannot debug a DLL produced in release mode. But the fact that it works in debug is probably related to an uninitialized variable. I've seen that a lot.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: as I'm dealing with an access violation, you might probably be right.

Comment: certainly sounds like undefined behavior to me, of which debug versions can be more forgiving. I had a very similar problem like this a few years ago with VxWorks,, My memory is hazy, but I _think_ I applied the offset reported in the crash to the disassembly from the object code to identify what function I was in, then went to the source code and quickly found the problem. Maybe something along those lines could be worth a try.

Comment: You can enable debug information for Release builds as well.

Comment: You should save map file for your build, then if you have a crash dump you can re-symbolize it.